# Sitecore WFFM Server Error in Form Designer

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Can anyone help me with this error? I am getting it when I attempt to open the form designer for Sitecore's Web Forms for Marketers

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[CompilerException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)]

Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.AssertResults(String sourceFile, CompilerResults results) +108
Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.Compile(String sourceFile, String code, String assemblyFile, StringCollection referencedAssemblies) +176
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.BuildControlAssembly(XmlNode fileNode, String& assemblyKey, String& assemblyFile) +380
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.GetControlAssembly(String controlName, String& assemblyKey) +179
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.ResolveType(String controlName, Boolean includeDynamicTypes) +46
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlSource.GetControlType(String namespacePrefix, String controlName, String mode, Boolean includeDynamicTypes) +114
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControlType(String controlName, String mode, Boolean includeDynamicTypes) +244
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(Control parent, String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric) +40
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl.AddControl(String name, String mode, Control pa rent, String placeholderID, String[] properties) +41
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.Forms_FormDesigner_a_195.Initialize() +7084
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.XmlControl..ctor() +72
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.Forms_FormDesigner_a_195..ctor() +9

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +1170
Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type) +91
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(Control parent, String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric) +53
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric) +25
Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(String controlName) +59
Sitecore.Shell.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) +88
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +143
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1477
```

I tried stepping through it but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Has this happened after an upgrade?

Comment: I don't think it has been upgraded recently but I checked out the project from subversion.

Comment: Ok, so maybe there are files missing from your source control. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before after performing an upgrade. In my case there were missing files in the site.

The problem was fixed by unzipping the WFFM install package, and comparing the files with what was in the Sitecore solution.

Eventually we found there were files in the package that weren't in the site.

n.b. Reinstalling the package didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Thank you. There were some discrepancies between our beta, live, and local environments.